# Getting errors while inserting text file rows into list of lists

Tags: python-2.7, list

**Code**

```
with open(dataset, "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line != None and line != "":
        arr = line.split(splitter)
        if (len(arr) < 3):
            continue
        user, item, rating = int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]), int(arr[2]) 
        # user,items, ratings are taken from text file
        if (len(train) <= user):
             train.append([])
        train[user].append([item]) # appending to list_of_lists `error here`
        train[user].append([rating]) #`ERROR here
```

**Output error**

```
train[user].append([item])
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Dataset**

```
   0    0       9
   0    12345   8
   0    4425    9
   1    20110   10
   1    1687759 10
   1    13490   8
   1    3259    10
```

Comment: You are appending variable or a string?What is [item] here append([item])?

Comment: In the dataset, user:1st column, item: 2nd column, rating of the user towards item : 3rd column

Comment: so appending each item and rating to the user in the training list

Comment: Is it raising the error at user 0 or 1?

Comment: When I am printing the train content, Its not showing 0th row, its printing 1st row and showing the error, list  index out of range

Comment: You aren't looping over the input file, just processing the first line in the code shown...